# Apostol - Mathematical Analysis - Theorem 1.1

Tags: analysis

I realize there are several questions dealing with Theorem 1.1 from Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis", but those questions are mostly about how to prove the result or the geometrical intuition around it. My question is about the application of the theorem. The theorem states:

If $a\leq b+\varepsilon$

for all $\varepsilon>0$, then

$a\leq b$.

Take an example.

$a=2$, $b=1$ and $e = 3$; $e := \varepsilon$ Then, $2 \leq 1 + 3$;

$2 \leq 4$

These meet the conditions required in the theorem.

But, now I get the absurd result: $2 \leq 1$

What is wrong in my usage of the theorem?

Comment: In "for all ε>0", you are missing "for all".

Answer (score 2):

The premise says **for all** $\epsilon>0.$ You have only shown the inequality holds for **one** $\epsilon$ (namely $\epsilon=3$). But it fails for $\epsilon = 1/2,$ for example, so the premise does not hold and you cannot draw the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks. Live to learn and fight again.

Answer (score 2):

It must hold **for all** $\varepsilon > 0$ that $a \leq b + \varepsilon$.

In your example, you consider $a = 2, b = 1$. Then that gives us $2 \leq 1 + \varepsilon$. However, notice, if you solve for $\varepsilon$, this requires $\varepsilon \geq 1$.

Since your example does not hold for **all** $\varepsilon>0$ - namely, for all $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ - then the conclusion doesn't follow, because the theorem itself doesn't apply.

In other words, if there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ for which $a > b + \varepsilon$, then the theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: Many many thanks. It is a universal quantifier.